# Updating tables with dotnet ef database update doesn't create tables

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core, npgsql

I've been following a tutorial to create a database by having a context class, and running the following commands:

dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration
dotnet ef database update

This did initially work for me, and the expected database was created.  Since then I have deleted the migration file and ran the process again, the update command seems to run fine, but when I check the database, the tables have not been created.

If I look in the migration file, I can see that it looks fine and appears to have the correct code in it to create the tables I want.

I don't think I've actually changed anything, so why has the update command stopped working as it did before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deleting you migration file didn't delete your database
so your database must be still existed however , if your create a new migration with the same name and update your database this will not effect you database since the migration is have been applied to your database
try to delete your database manually from SQL explorer then try update-database

Comment: I have manually deleted it from the explorer, but getting the same issue.  Do I need to use dotnet ef to remove the migration too, or does that just delete the file?

Comment: delete the entire migration folder, i think the contextmodelsnapshot saves the migrations state

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove all migrations from your Migration folder in dot net project.
2. Create a new migration from CLI or from wherever you are making. (dotnet-ef migrations add..)
3. In the .cs file of this new migration file, comment all the CREATE TABLES commands for existing tables i.e. migration.Create...this one (These will be in the Up method of your migration file)
4. Just keep CREATE commands for only required tables.
5. Apply the update.(dotnet-ef database update)
   Will work like a charm.